# How to pack python source code so that they change into ".so" files

Tags: python, linux, pack

I had wrote a python project with many ".py" files. Now I need to pack them and make them become ".so" files in order to meet the work's condition. But I had no method after a long thinking. Could you please give me some help ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For generating an .so file, you need a compiled language. I'm not sure, how close you can get to that on Python basis, but [Cython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cython) seems worth a look, especially, since the lower diagram of wikipedia articel already shows a .so file.

Comment: Thank you for reply.I have saw the article in wikipedia.Of course,I haven't heard of the Cython.Now I know the Cython used for generating the python's extension modules fast and the picture in wikipedia also displayed the ".so" file.Therefore,I also think I need to use Cython if I want to change ".py" into ".so".Thank you aganin!

Answer (score 2):

You should check [the wheel format](http://wheel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). As I known, the pure python source code(".py") can't compile into ".so"

Comment: [Cython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cython).I forgot to give the link,sorry.You can see it.

Comment: @cwfighter I know Cython. That why I say *pure* python source code(maybe that is not a property statement, I just want to express kind of source code can execute by CPython without compiling)

Comment: Oh,Thanks for your explaination!I see it now.